# Will using shared_ptr for returning pointers from a method always save me from memory leaks?

Tags: c++

I'm a c++ newbie, my code currently new's up on the heap in several places without calling delete. I know I need to do something about this.

My typical usage is where I new up a class instance in another classes member method then the method returns the pointer to the object.

If i change the return types from MyType* to std::tr1::shared_ptr will this fix my code to not leak memory?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
Also likewise, I currently store new'ed up objects as MyType* as a value in a std:map. This map is a private member to a class instance. If I simply change this to std::tr1::shared_ptr will this clear up these when it's owner (class) falls out of scope?

Thanks again

Comment: If you've been writing your code without caring for memory management then you've likely got a bigger problem than leaks.

Comment: It's my first weekend writing c++ - give me a little leeway.

Comment: Perhaps show an example of where you would use a `shared_pointer`? Chances are it's overkill for your uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reasonable band-aid, sure.

A shared pointer is a *reference-counted* pointer. So as long as one or more `shared_ptr`s exist pointing to an object, that object will be kept alive. The problem occurs if you have circular references. Then the reference count will never reach 0, and the object(s) will never be deleted.

So `shared_ptr` * still* require you to understand what you're doing and think about object ownership, as you always have to do in C++. But it simplifies some otherwise complex scenarios, where determining ownership is hard.

But the *real* fix to your problem is to:

- minimize how much you allocate with `new`. Can the object instead be stored on the stack? Can the object be rewritten as a RAII class, so that a small wrapper object is allocated on the stack (or elsewhere with automatic storage duration), and which, through its constructors and destructors, manages a heap-allocated memory resource? Then, as long as that object exists, its allocated memory will be preserved, and once it is destroyed, it will delete its allocated memory.
- when you allocate objects with `new`, put them in *one of* the smart pointer classes. `shared_ptr` is popular because it is the one that comes closest to looking like a garbage collector, but it isn't, and if you treat it as one and use it as an excuse to not think about memory management, then it won't work. Understand *all* the smart pointer classes (scoped_ptr and auto_ptr in C++03, or unique_ptr replacing both in C++11, shared_ptr and weak_ptr), and use the one that best fits your scenario.
- think about ownership. Any time you allocate memory, you need to determine an owner, whose lifetime will control the lifetime of the memory allocation. Think about how long a lifetime your allocation needs, and have another object (whose lifetime is automatically managed, probably because it is on the stack) `delete` your memory when its destructor is called.

There's no quick and easy fix. The way to handle memory management in C++ is to avoid memory management. Delegate it out to your objects. If you're calling `delete` in your own code, you're doing it wrong. Often, you don't even need `new`, but *if* you do, assign ownership to a smart pointer immediately, and let that call `delete` for you.

As a rule of thumb, unless you're a library writer, you shouldn't write either `new` or `delete`. You should virtually never use raw pointers, and only when it is absolutely necessary, use smart pointers. Let your classes do the heavy lifting. Don't be afraid to put them on the stack, pass them by value, and let them handle their resources internally.

Comment: @jalf: library writers?? please explain. I am writing a reusable library.

Comment: @CodingQuant: welll, *someone eventually has to `new` and `delete` chunks of memory. But it can usually be hidden within libraries. For exampple, when you insert an object into the standard library `vector`, it internally allocates and frees that object, and you never have to call `new` or `delete`. But the library writer who wrote the `vector` class had to call them. So if you're writing library code, you may need to use new/delete directly, but otherwise, it's something that's usually best left to libraries. You just use the library, and it does what needs doing internally

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to C++ there are a few points with pointer management you need to understand and accept, regardless of whether you're using shared_ptr or not.

It is more than likely in your use of C++ you will need to use new and assign its return pointer to a class pointer that you have declared. I believe it is advisable to take the time to understand what is going on there, even if you write a small test program and watch the constructor execute in the debugger.

If you use classes like std::string, its constructors and destructor will do string pointer management for you, but I believe it is a good idea to understand what is going on behind the scenes in that class, if nothing more than reading the documentation.

As another example, you cannot use some classes, without a lot of detailed reading of the API, or you'll get problems. I once worked at company that used a commercial class package years ago. Someone had written a multi-threaded program using this package's thread pool class.

The documentation clearly said you can't just exit with outstanding threads. Yet I saw where the author of the program did not bother to synch up and shutdown all threads on exit, and wound up throwing exceptions, when their program exited. And this was on a commercial financial product.

My suggestion is don't look to get saved from performing pointer management. There are std classes like string that can reduce your headaches, but nothing will prevent problems other than your own diligence and testing.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you understand how tr1 shared pointers work, yes.

Look at Boost C++ shared_ptr<> also - it might be more what you want.

Comment: 1: why is Boost's shared_ptr "more what he wants" than `tr1` or `std` shared_ptr? and 2 why imply that he needs to understand how shared pointers work, *but not actually explain it*?

Comment: Shared pointers can solve problems regardless of whether you understand them or not, they don't magically start working when you figure them out; they should be understood, so some vague explanation could be helpful. There's also absolutely no reason to suggest boost's shared_ptr over the built-in (now that most compilers offer TR1 or C++11 smart pointers).

Comment: @peachykeen: Not true. C++11 `shared_ptr` is more or less equivalent to Boost's version. But TR1 was based on an *older* Boost implementation that didn't have as many features. Pointer aliasing, and various other techniques, are missing from the TR1 version. Just use Boost if you don't have access to the C++11 version.

Comment: @NicolBolas While you are correct in general, I doubt the additional features will be important here. Still, good for the OP to know for future reference. Do any current/recent compilers not provide C++11 versions of the smart pointers?